# Can the floating-point status flag FE_UNDERFLOW set when the result is not sub-normal?

Tags: c, floating-point, ieee-754

While investigating floating-point exception status flags, I came across the curious case of a status flag `FE_UNDERFLOW` set when not expected.

This is similar to [When does underflow occur?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42277132/2410359) yet goes into a corner case that may be a C specification issue or FP hardware defect.

```
// pseudo code
//                       s bias_expo implied "mantissa"
w = smallest_normal;  // 0 000...001 (1)     000...000
x = w * 2;            // 0 000...010 (1)     000...000
y = next_smaller(x);  // 0 000...001 (1)     111...111
round_mode(FE_TONEAREST);
clear_status_flags();
z = y/2;              // 0 000...001 (1)     000...000

FE_UNDERFLOW is set!?
```

I did not expect `FE_UNDERFLOW` to be set as `z` above is normal, not a sub-normal.
I expect `FE_UNDERFLOW` when the **result** of an earlier floating-point operation **was subnormal** with a loss of precision.  In this case there is a loss of precision.

I tried this with my `float` and `long double` and had the same result.

After much investigation, I noted that `__STDC_IEC_559__` is *not* defined.

**Questions**

1. If `__STDC_IEC_559__` is defined, what is the correct state of underflow in this case?
2. With lack of a defined `__STDC_IEC_559__` am I stuck with "Implementations that do not define `__STDC_IEC_559__` are not required to conform to these
   specifications." C11 or is there some C specification that indicates this result is incorrect?
3. Since this is certainly a result of my hardware (processor), your result may differ and that would be interesting to know.

---

Follows is some test code that demos this.  At first I suspected it is because `FLT_EVAL_METHOD = 2` on my machine, yet then I tried similar code with `long double` and the same result.

```
// These 2 includes missing in original post, yet in my true test code
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>

#include <fenv.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define N (sizeof excepts/sizeof excepts[0])
void Report_IEC_FP_exception_status_flags(const char *s) {
  printf("%s", s);
  int excepts[] = { //
      FE_DIVBYZERO, FE_INEXACT, FE_INVALID, FE_OVERFLOW, FE_UNDERFLOW, };
  const char *excepts_str[N] = { //
      "FE_DIVBYZERO", "FE_INEXACT", "FE_INVALID", "FE_OVERFLOW", "FE_UNDERFLOW", };
  int excepts_val[N];

  for (unsigned i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    excepts_val[i] = fetestexcept(excepts[i]);
  }
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    if (excepts_val[i]) printf(" %s", excepts_str[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
  fflush(stdout);
}
#undef N

void test2(float f, int round_mode, const char *name) {
  union {
    float f;
    uint32_t u32;
    } x = { .f = f};

  printf("x:%+17a %08lX normal:%c round_mode:%d %s\n", //
  f, (unsigned long) x.u32, isnormal(f) ? 'Y' : 'n', round_mode, name);
  if (feclearexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT)) puts("Clear Fail");
  Report_IEC_FP_exception_status_flags("Before:");

  f /= 2;

  Report_IEC_FP_exception_status_flags("After :");
  printf("y:%+17a %08lX normal:%c\n\n", 
      f,(unsigned long) x.u32, isnormal(f) ? 'Y' : 'n');
}
```

Driver

```
// In same file as above
int main(void) {
  #ifdef __STDC_IEC_559__
    printf("__STDC_IEC_559__ = %d\n", __STDC_IEC_559__);
  #else
    printf("__STDC_IEC_559__ = not define\n");
  #endif

  float f = FLT_MIN;
  printf("FLT_EVAL_METHOD = %d\n", FLT_EVAL_METHOD);
  printf("FLT_MIN:%+17a\n", f);
  f *= 2.0f;
  test2(f, FE_TONEAREST, "FE_TONEAREST");
  f = nextafterf(f, 0);
  test2(f, FE_TONEAREST, "FE_TONEAREST");   // *** problem? ***
  f = nextafterf(f, 0);
  test2(f, FE_TONEAREST, "FE_TONEAREST");
}
```

Output

```
__STDC_IEC_559__ = not define
FLT_EVAL_METHOD = 2
FLT_MIN:        +0x1p-126
x:        +0x1p-125 01000000 normal:Y round_mode:0 FE_TONEAREST
Before:
After :
y:        +0x1p-126 01000000 normal:Y

x: +0x1.fffffep-126 00FFFFFF normal:Y round_mode:0 FE_TONEAREST
Before:
After : FE_INEXACT FE_UNDERFLOW                *** Why FE_UNDERFLOW? ***
y:        +0x1p-126 00FFFFFF normal:Y          *** Result is normal  ***

x: +0x1.fffffcp-126 00FFFFFE normal:Y round_mode:0 FE_TONEAREST
Before:
After :
y: +0x1.fffffcp-127 00FFFFFE normal:n
```

Ref

[IEEE_754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)

Implementation notes:

GNU C11 (GCC) version 6.4.0 (i686-pc-cygwin)
    compiled by GNU C version 6.4.0, GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.5-p10, MPC version 1.0.3, isl version 0.14 or 0.13

glibc 2.26 released.

Intel Xeon W3530, 64-bit OS (Windows 7)

---

[Minor Update]  The illustrative print of the quotient as an 32-bit hex number should have used `y.u32`.  This does not change the function under test

```
// printf("y:%+17a %08lX normal:%c\n\n", 
//    f,(unsigned long) x.u32, isnormal(f) ? 'Y' : 'n');
union {
  float f;
  uint32_t u32;
} y = { .f = f};
printf("y:%+17a %08lX normal:%c\n\n", 
    f,(unsigned long) y.u32, isnormal(f) ? 'Y' : 'n');
//                    ^^^^^
```

Comment: What implementations did you test this on?

Comment: @EOF notes appended to post.  Sorry just one platform so far.  Yet a good idea for others - I'll try another later.

Comment: As far as I am aware, if `__STDC_IEC_559__` is not defined then you are indeed stuck without any specifications for details of FP behavior, except any that your implementation itself may provide.

Comment: I get this on my Raspberry Pi: `__STDC_IEC_559__ = 1
FLT_EVAL_METHOD = 0
FLT_MIN:        +0x1p-126
x:        +0x1p-125 01000000 normal:Y round_mode:0 FE_TONEAREST
Before:
After :
y:        +0x1p-126 01000000 normal:Y

x: +0x1.fffffep-126 00FFFFFF normal:Y round_mode:0 FE_TONEAREST
Before:
After : FE_INEXACT FE_UNDERFLOW
y:        +0x1p-126 00FFFFFF normal:Y

x: +0x1.fffffcp-126 00FFFFFE normal:Y round_mode:0 FE_TONEAREST
Before:
After :
y: +0x1.fffffcp-127 00FFFFFE normal:n` So the same behavior *with* `__STDC_IEC_559__`.

Comment: @eof, thanks- glad you could run it. Yours reports appears to only differ in  `__STDC_IEC_559__ = 1 FLT_EVAL_METHOD = 0` - hmmmm.

Comment: Interesting.  To compile your code successfully and without warnings on gcc 4.8.5 (Linux / x86_64), I need to add headers `float.h` and `math.h`.  Having done so, I find that `__STDC_IEC_559__` **is** defined (to 1), and that `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` is defined to 0, according to the program's output.  Otherwise, however, I observe the same output presented in the question.

Comment: @EOF Consider trying `long double` math by adding `long double fld = (1.0L - LDBL_EPSILON/2)*(LDBL_MIN * 2.0L);` at the beginning of `test2()` and replace `f /= 2;` with `fld /= 2;` Same `FE_UNDERFLOW`?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I also did  have those 2 `#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>` and omitted in post -post updated.

Comment: It is conceivable that your more recent GCC and/or glibc declines to define `__STDC_IEC_559__` precisely because of small variances from the requirements of Annex F such as the behavior you observe seems to be.  However, having only a Wikipedia summary of IEEE-754 to go by, I cannot be certain whether the behavior you observe in fact fails to conform.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I also suspect many platforms are nearly _IEEE-754_, yet not quite 100%.

Comment: @chux You're also missing `#include`s for `main()`. Also, `long double` seems to report `FE_INEXACT` and `FE_UNDERFLOW` too (assuming no optimizations to avoid the computation alltogether), but I haven't checked whether `long double` is different from `double` on the Raspian gcc.

Comment: My `long double` is an [80-bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_extended_precision_format) one.

Comment: @chux I've just checked, `gcc version 4.9.2 (Raspbian 4.9.2-10)` for ARMv7 with vfpv4 and NEON has 8-byte `long double`, same as `double`.

Comment: Perhaps footnote 371 of C 2011 is relevant: "IEC 60559 allows different definitions of underflow. They all result in the same values, but differ on when the floating-point exception is raised."

Comment: It looks like the implementation can choose to [detect underflow before or after rounding](http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/754/email/msg04221.html), so the result is correct.

Comment: @nwellnhof  "The implementor may choose how these events are detected,
but shall detect these events in the same way for all operations." looks reasonable, but is that  choice of before/after underflow detection traceable to an IEC 60559 specification as reported by C11 or  a sage interpretation?  It seems to be in "The relevant clause in the 2008 standard is 7.5." - Guess I'll need to buy the spec.

Comment: @nwellnhof [Two definitions were allowed for the determination of the 'tiny' condition: before or after rounding ...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754_revision) supports your [good reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46611633/can-the-floating-point-status-flag-fe-underflow-set-when-the-result-is-not-sub-n#comment80177104_46611633) and goes further with "_recommended_ that only tininess after rounding..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although not intended as a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), input from various commenters [@John Bollinger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46611633/can-the-floating-point-status-flag-fe-underflow-set-when-the-result-is-not-sub-n#comment80177027_46611633), [@nwellnhof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46611633/can-the-floating-point-status-flag-fe-underflow-set-when-the-result-is-not-sub-n#comment80177104_46611633) and further research leads to:

> Can the floating-point status flag FE_UNDERFLOW set when the result is not sub-normal?

**Yes**, in narrow situations - when the math answer lies between sub-normals and normals.  See following.

---

"Underflow" occurs when:

> The result underflows if the magnitude of the mathematical result is so small that the mathematical result cannot be represented, without extraordinary roundoff error, in an object of the specified type.  C11  7.12.1 Treatment of error conditions

The `z = y/2;` above is 1) inexact (due to rounding) and 2) maybe considered "too small".

---

**Math**

The `z = y/2;` can be thought of going through 2 stages: dividing and rounding.  The mathematical quotient, with unlimited precision, is less than the smallest normal number `FLT_MIN` and more than the greatest [sub-normal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number) `nextafterf(FLT_MIN,0)`. Depending  on rounding mode, the final answer is either one of those two.  With `FE_TONEAREST`, `z` is assigned `FLT_MIN`, a normal number.

**Spec**

The C spec below and  to IEC 60559 indicate

> The "underflow" floating-point exception is raised whenever a result is tiny (essentially subnormal or zero) and suffers loss of accuracy.<sup>358</sup> C11 §F.10 7.
> <sup>358</sup> IEC 60559 allows different definitions of underflow. They all result in the same values, but differ on when the floating-point exception is raised.

and

> Two definitions were allowed for the determination of the 'tiny' condition: **before or after rounding** the infinitely precise result to working precision, with unbounded exponent.
>
> Annex U of 754r recommended that only tininess after rounding and inexact as loss of accuracy be a cause for underflow signal.  [wiki reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754_revision#Discussed_but_not_included)

(My emphasis)

---

**Q & A**

> 1. If **STDC_IEC_559** is defined, what is the correct state of underflow in this case?

The underflow flag may be set or left alone in this case. Either complies. There is a preference though, for not setting the underflow flag.

> 2 With lack of a defined **STDC_IEC_559** am I stuck with "Implementations that do not define **STDC_IEC_559** are not required to conform to these specifications." C11 or is there some C specification that indicates this result is incorrect?

The setting of the underflow flag result in not incorrect.  The FP spec allows this behavior.  It also allows to not set the underflow flag.

> 3 Since this is certainly a result of my hardware (processor), your result may differ and that would be interesting to know.

On another platform, where `__STDC_IEC_559__ = not define` and `FLT_EVAL_METHOD = 0`, the `FE_INEXACT FE_UNDERFLOW` flags were both set, just like in the above tst case.  The issue applies to `float, double, long double`.

---

If the mathematical answer lies in the grey "Between" zone below, it will get rounding down to a sub-normal `double` or up to the normal `double` `DBL_MIN` depending on its value and rounding mode.  If rounded down, then `FE_UNDERFLOW` is certainly set.  If rounded up, then `FE_UNDERFLOW` may be set or not depending on when  determination of the 'tiny' condition is applied.

[image: Number line near DBL_MIN]

Comment: I look forward to other answers, especially one that cites the floating point spec.

Comment: Relevant, worth reading: http://www.jhauser.us/arithmetic/SoftFloat-3/doc/SoftFloat-FAQ.html (scroll down to "I discovered a case where, even though tininess..."). Extra (for better understanding): https://stackoverflow.com/a/67127805/1778275. Also: I think that for subnormals "more dynamic range" is not worth of all the implementation issues w.r.t. subnormal numbers. Maybe it was better to use `±(1.F) × 2^-127` format over `±(0.F) × 2^-126` format?

Comment: @pmor Hmmm, " to use ±(1.F) × 2^-127 format over ±(0.F) × 2^-126 format" --> appears to lose the property of of 2 small FP values `a, b` where `a != b`, then `a-b` does not round 0.0 using  ±(0.F) × 2^-126.  Yet may round to 0.0 with ±(1.F) × 2^-127.  That is a prime reason for sub-normals.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I remember that William Kahan once wrote about such `a != b => a-b != 0.0` case for small FP values. Because of that the rationale of using ±(0.F) × 2^-126 format (more dynamic range despite of less precision) is clear.