# What are the risks of parsing numeric strings into floats?

Tags: parsing, floating-point

In this API (https://docs.gemini.com/rest-api/#current-order-book), it says:

> The quantities and prices returned are returned as strings rather than
>   numbers. The numbers returned are exact, not rounded, and it can be
>   dangerous to treat them as floating point numbers.

Why would it be "dangerous" to treat the numeric strings as floats? Is it just the loss of precision? If it's the loss of precision, technically it's more "dangerous" to return floats in the first place. This quote seems to imply that the act of parsing floats might be "dangerous". Why might that be so?

Comment: How precise / big / small can these prices be? Any chance you are working with values non-representable in floats?

Comment: It's the loss of precision.

Comment: Because modern computers predominantly use binary floating point and many decimal values like 0.1 cannot be expressed in binary.

Answer (score 2):

> What are the risks of parsing numeric strings into floats?

**Mapping infinite to finite**

Common floating point types have a finite member set/size.  Say the `float` took up 32-bits.  That leads to about 2<sup>32</sup> different `float` values.  A *string* has limitless combinations.  Something has to give, regardless if the target `float` is encoded using binary, decimal or [stone knives and bears skins 1:40](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F226oWBHvvI).

Risk: Assuming all values are encode-able.

**Decimal to binary**

Typical [floats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) employ a *binary* notation/fraction while a *string* is often written using *decimal* digits.

`"1.234"` has no *exact* equivalent value as a `float`.  Instead the parsing yields a nearby `float`.  The `float` itself is *exact*, but not the same *exact* value as 1.234.

Risk: Assuming conversion was exact equivalent.

**Range**

Even if imprecision is tolerated, `float` has a range, perhaps +/-10<sup>38</sup>,  +/-10<sup>308</sup> or the like.  10000! is not expected to be representable.

Value can only get so small too, before they are converted to 0.0.

Risk: Overflow/underflow.

---

The real *danger* is lack of understanding of how floating point differs in various cases from *real* math and how to cope.  With these, subtleties can lead to infinite loops, lost money, crashed code, or inconsistencies across platforms.

In *math* there is the [real number_line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_line).  With `float`, the line is "dotted".  [Zoomed in example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46671801/2410359) [example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46619906/2410359)