# IEEE 754: rationale for format: subnormal and normal numbers

Tags: format, ieee-754, subnormal-numbers

Can someone please clarify:

1. Why exactly the format of subnormal numbers is `±(0.F) × 2^-126` and not `±(1.F) × 2^-127`?
2. Why exactly the format of normal numbers is: `±(1.F) × 2^exp` and not, say, `±(11.F) × 2^exp`, or, say,  `±(10.F) × 2^exp`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the properties of both format using simplified example. For the sake of simplicity I use formats `0.F × 10^-2` and `1.F × 10^-3`, where `F` has 2 decimal digits and there is no `±`.

Min (non-zero) / max values:

```
Format          Min value (non-zero)           Max value
0.F × 10^-2     0.01 × 10^-2 = 0.0001          0.99 × 10^-2 = 0.0099
1.F × 10^-3     1.00 × 10^-3 = 0.001           9.99 × 10^-3 = 0.00999
```

Here is the graphical representation:

[image]

Here we see that starting from value `0.001` format `1.F × 10^-3` does not allow anymore to represent smaller values. However, format `0.F × 10^-2` allows to represent smaller values. Here is the zoomed-in version:

[image]

Conclusion: from the graphical representation we see that the properties of format `0.F × 10^-2` over format `1.F × 10^-3` are:

1. gives more dynamic range: `log10(max_real / min_real)`: `1.99 vs 0.99`
2. gives less precision: less values can be represented: `100 vs 900`

It seems that for subnormals IEEE 754 preferred `more dynamic range` despite of `less precision`. Hence, that is why the format of subnormal numbers is `±(0.F) × 2^-126` and not `±(1.F) × 2^-127`.

Comment: @chux - Reinstate Monica Can you comment on that? Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

A floating-point format represents numbers using a sign (− or +), an exponent (an integer in some range *e*<sub>min</sub> to *e*<sub>max</sub>, inclusive), and a significand that is a numeral of *p* digits in base *b*, where *b* is the fixed base for the format and *p* is called the precision. We will consider a binary format, in which *b* is two.

Let the digits of the significand be *f*<sub>0</sub>, *f*<sub>−1</sub>, *f*<sub>−2</sub>,… *f*<sub>1−*p*</sub>, so the significand is sum<sub>−p<i≤0</sub> f<sub>*i*</sub>•*b*<sup>*i*</sup>, and the value represented is (−1)<sup>*s*</sup>•*b*<sup>*e*</sup>•sum<sub>−p<i≤0</sub> f<sub>*i*</sub>•*b*<sup>*i*</sup>, where *s* is a bit for the sign and *e* is the exponent.

If *f*<sub>0</sub> is zero, we can omit it from the sum, and the value represented equals (−1)<sup>*s*</sup>•*b*<sup>*e*</sup>•sum<sub>−p<i≤−1</sub> f<sub>*i*</sub>•*b*<sup>*i*</sup> = (−1)<sup>*s*</sup>•*b*<sup>*e*−1</sup>•sum<sub>−p<i≤−1</sub> f<sub>*i*</sub>•*b*<sup>*i*+1</sup> = (−1)<sup>*s*</sup>•*b*<sup>*e*−1</sup>•sum<sub>1−p<i≤0</sub> f<sub>*i*−1</sub>•*b*<sup>*i*</sup>. Therefore, when *f*<sub>0</sub> is zero, and *e* is not *e*<sub>min</sub>, there are two representations of the number. Encoding both of them would be wasteful, so we desire an encoding scheme that does not encode both representations.

We accomplish this:

- Some value *E* encodes the exponent *e*. The values of *s* and *f*<sub>−1</sub> to *f*<sub>1−*p*</sub> are stored directly as bits.
- If *E* is zero, *e* is *e*<sub>min</sub> and *f*<sub>0</sub> is zero.
- If *E* is not zero, *e* is *E*−*bias* and *f*<sub>0</sub> is one, where *bias* is 1−*e*<sub>min</sub>.
- (A special value of *E* may be reserved to represent infinities and NaNs, not discussed further here.)

This representation and this encoding scheme answer the questions:

> Why exactly the format of subnormal numbers is ±(0.*F*) × 2<sup>− 126</sup> and not ±(1.F) × 2<sup>−127</sup>?

Subnormal numbers of the form ±(1.F) × 2<sup>−127</sup> would fail to include zero and would include numbers not in the represented numbers of the format, as they would have numbers with non-zero digits below that of the lowest non-zero digit in the chosen set. (The lowest digit of the form described in the first paragraph corresponds to *b*<sup>*e*<sub>min</sub>+(1−*p*)</sup>, whereas numbers in the form ±(1.F) × 2<sup>−127</sup> would have a lowest digit corresponding to *b*<sup>*e*<sub>min</sub>−1+(1−*p*)</sup>.)

> Why exactly the format of normal numbers is: ±(1.F) × 2<sup>exp</sup> and not, say, ±(11.F) × 2<sup>exp</sup>, or, say,  ±(10.F) × 2<sup>exp</sup>?

Where the decimal point (or “radix point”) lies in the significand is irrelevant, as long as it is fixed. A representation described using the decimal point just after the first digit, as used herein, is equivalent to a representation using decimal point after the last digit or at any other position, with a suitable adjustment to the exponent bounds: The same set of numbers is represented and the arithmetic properties are identical. So, in considering the difference between 1.F and 11.F, we do not care where the decimal point lies. However, we do care about how many digits are represented. A floating-point format uses a representation with a fixed number of digits. 11.F has one more digit than 1.F, and we have no reason to encode that.

As for the difference between 11.F and 10.F, the reason the normal/subnormal distinction exists is because arithmetically there are two representations of the same number **if the first digit is zero** and the exponent is not at the minimum. Specifying one form as normal form allows us to eliminate these duplicate representations. However 11.F and 10.F represent different numbers, so there is no duplicate to eliminate and no reason to say one of these is normal and the other is not.

Comment: `why not 11.F`: ok, the answer is clear: less precision. `rationale for format of subnormal numbers` (FSN for short): the answer is in the style "because the standard says so", which does not really give the true arguments in favor of the current FSN. `would fail to include zero`: currently zero is a dedicated class (`FP_ZERO`), and, hence, there is no need to require from FSN to be able to represent zero. `would include numbers not in the represented numbers of the format`: however, which exactly advantages are given by format `±(0.F) × 2^-126` over format `±(1.F) × 2^-127`?

Comment: @pmor: What in this answer has the form “because the standard says so”? The set of numbers representable in a floating-point format arises from the format. Then the subnormal numbers are those for which the first digit is zero and cannot be made non-zero by adjusting the exponent. This arises purely as mathematical-logical necessity and is not “because the standard says so”.

Comment: @pmor: Your other questions approach the issue from a bad viewpoint. We are not constructing descriptions of subnormal or normal numbers based on what we would like them to be; we do not choose subnormal numbers to have some format because we want more bits for them or whatever. They arise because we already have a floating-point format and find are partitioning it into useful classes. Saying floating-point numbers are those with a format 1.F•2^−127 would be wrong because it includes numbers that do not exist in the set being partitioned.

Comment: @pmor: Note that I am interpreting the “F” of 1.F•2^−127 here to be the same F as used for the trailing bits of the significand elsewhere, i.e., it has 23 bits for the IEEE-754 binary32 format. That means it has too many bits, so 1.F•2^−127 includes numbers that are not part of the binary32 format. If you mean “F” to mean only whatever bits would be available in the binary32 format, then “1.F•@^−127” is not an apt description because it is a different presentation from the description of the floating-point format, which uses a fixed number of digits for the significand.