# Level of precision loss when an underflow occurs

Tags: c++, underflow

I understand what an underflow is and when it could occur based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42277132/when-does-underflow-occur).

However, my question is that given that an underflow has occurred, what determines the amount of loss in precision?

I'm computing an array in C++ and I do see some numerical errors such as `1.333e-18` when the array should actually be `0` everywhere. However, the numerical error is different across the array. Is there a rule to determine the amount of precision loss?

Comment: @JGroven I'm asking the way to determine the *amount* of precision loss though? Not why, but how much?

Comment: The first answer has a link that talks about the normalization and de-normalization process, which (I think) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Consider fixed point math as well if you need a firm control of digit representation and error.

Comment: You start losing significant digits at 1.2e-38 and have none left at 1.4e-45.  1.3e-18 is not a denormal value, just the normal outcome of imprecise calculation.  If you know that the mathematical result should be 0 then you have the unusual convenience of knowing the absolute error.

Comment: It depends: `123456789.0f - 1.0f` will give you an unexpected result.