# Why does subtraction of smaller character with greater character give a big positive integer instead of a negative integer?

Tags: c, char, ascii

**When I subtract a larger character with a smaller one, I'm getting a huge positive number instead of a much smaller, negative number, while assigning it to a long long int variable.**

If I subtract ' N ' with ' A 'and if I assign it a long long int variable, it turns out to be 18446744073709551605 instead of -13.

When I use abs() function while computing, I get the value correctly, but obviously it will be positive instead of negative. So how to get the value correctly?

```
char s[] = "ABCT";
char t[] = "PBDI";
long long int curr_diff;
for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
curr_diff = (t[i] - '0') - (s[i] - '0');
printf("Current value : %llu\n", curr_diff);
}
```

**Result from my code**

```
Current value : 15
Current value : 0
Current value : 1
Current value : 18446744073709551605
```

**Expected result**

```
Current value : 15
Current value : 0
Current value : 1
Current value : -11
```

Comment: Why would someone use `printf` in C++ code???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When does underflow occur?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42277132/when-does-underflow-occur)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`printf("Current value : %llu\n", curr_diff);`

You are printing `long long unsigned` value. Use `%lld` to get the right output

Comment: Eliminating the risk of using the wrong format string is a good reason for using `std::cout` over `printf` as it's type safe.

Comment: To re-word for clarity: OP is trying to print `long long int` using the specifier that is meant for `unsigned long long int`. The behaviour of the program is undefined.